# How can I encrypt an entire file?

Tags: spring, encryption, spring-security, jasypt

Can we encrypt entire spring application.properties using Jasypt

```
application.properties

 propOne=ENC(asdfafd)
 propTwo=ENC(adf;lkj$1)
```

Comment: this maybe help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt

Comment: even that has only single property encryption